# How do I fix the ordering in Microsoft excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, spreadsheet

When I try to sort a column, the sorting isn't exactly right. The content in the column contains text and numbers.

Here's an excel file where the ordering is wrong: https://www.dropbox.com/s/grbg0ic2r5fylpw/sample.xls?dl=0

Can someone help me fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You are going to need to make the last numbers all 3 digits.  Excel sorts Text fields Character by character.  So "11" comes before "2".

Answer (score 1):

Excel sorts text fields Character by Character so text wise "11" come before "2".  So you need to add leading `0` to the numbers.  "002" comes before "011"

To do that:

In an empty column put the following formula in the first row:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))) & TEXT(--TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))),999)),"000")
```

Then copy down.

[image]

Then copy the new column and paste just the values on the old column.  Then your sort should work.

If you want to keep the original formatting then leave the new column and sort on the new column instead.  You can hide the new column.

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for some of the contents. But is there anyway to do this with longer text and numbers?

Comment: What is the max count on the trailing numbers?  Just add that many `0` to the `"000"` at the end of the formula.

Comment: @user5389574 give me an example of one that did not work.

Comment: I was trying to get it to work on a list like this one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfkc5h5eus1i2hu/longerSample.xls?dl=0

Comment: yes, you are right this will not work.  It worked for your entire first list.  At this point you can do a couple of things.  Try to come up with formulas for every contingency or write vba to do it.  I do not have time to write the myriad of formulas for every contingency.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like there are some formatting issues in the data. I selected all your data, opened a new spreadsheet, copied and clicked on paste special. I choose values and numbers. This brings back the data without any formatting in them. I was then able to sort this properly.

Comment: This is not an answer.  It is a comment, and I know you cannot comment, but usually comments posted as answers actually get down voted, regardless if they do or do not have enough points to comment.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the data in the column A
- Use the Data/Text to columns wizard to split the original data using **space** as the delimiter, but put the destination = $B$1 at Step 3 so as to leave the original intact.
- Sort on columns B, C, D, etc, in that order
- Delete all except column A

If this will need to be done repetitively, record a macro while you do these steps, then edit the macro to recognize the appropriate ranges automatically.